# iOS: ShinobiChart: Continious display for discontinuous data

Tags: ios, shinobi

I'm using `ShinobiChart` to draw candlestick stock chart.
My data is discontinuous, so that there will gaps on chart.

Anybody knows how can I make it show **continuously**? Cannot find it in documentation...[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found it. For your reference:
Instead of adding `SChartDateTimeAxis` you instead should add `SChartDiscontiniousDateTimeAxis`.

Then for any gap in dataSeries you have to explicitly exclude time period with `addExcludedTimePeriod:`. (You can do it my checking whether next day is the same a next date in the dataSeries).

```
SChartDiscontinuousDateTimeAxis *xAxis = [[SChartDiscontinuousDateTimeAxis alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger iter = 0; iter < self.quotes.count - 1; iter++) {

    NSDate* thisDate = ((TBHistoricQuote*)self.quotes[iter]).date;
    NSDate* nextDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                                   value:1
                                                                  toDate:thisDate
                                                                 options:0];
    NSDate* nextSeriesElementDate = ((TBHistoricQuote*)self.quotes[iter+1]).date;


    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];


    if ([nextDate compare:nextSeriesElementDate] == NSOrderedAscending ) {

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                   fromDate:nextDate
                                                     toDate:nextSeriesElementDate
                                                    options:0];

        [xAxis addExcludedTimePeriod:[[SChartTimePeriod alloc] initWithStart:nextDate andLength:[[SChartDateFrequency alloc] initWithDay:components.day]]];
    }

}

self.chart.xAxis = xAxis;
```